# Having unspecified errors and a few issues when running google maps

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

**ISSUE 1**

I tried to get the geo code after entering the address. After i clicked on the GeoCode button, it prompts me unspecified errors.

I have a page Register.aspx (no update panel) with a button "View", it will call ucGoogleMap.ascx when i clicked on the button.

Below is the javascript and html codes in ucGoogleMap.ascx.

```js
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $get('<%=height.ClientID%>').value = $(window).height();
    });

   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

   function geocodePosition(pos) {
       debugger;
        geocoder.geocode({
                latLng: pos
            }, function (responses) {
                if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
                    updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
                } else {
                    updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
                }
            });
    }

    function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
        document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
    }

    function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
            latLng.lat(),
            latLng.lng()
        ].join(', ');
    }

    function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
        document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
    }

    function initialize() {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(19.0606917, 72.83624970000005);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
            zoom: 18,
            center: latLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var domainName = document.getElementById('<%=hdnDomainName.ClientID %>').value;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            title: 'Point A',
            map: map,
            icon: domainName + 'Images/maker.png',
            draggable: true
        });

        // Update current position info.
        updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
        geocodePosition(latLng);

        // Add dragging event listeners.
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function () {
            updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function () {
            updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
            updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
            updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
            geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
        });
    }

    function codeAddress() {
        debugger;
        var domainName = document.getElementById('<%=hdnDomainName.ClientID %>').value;
        var address = document.getElementById('<%= txtAddress.ClientID %>').value;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address' : address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
                    zoom: 18,
                    center: results[0].geometry.location,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });
               // map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title: 'Point A',
                    map: map,
                    icon: domainName + 'Images/maker.png',
                    draggable: true     
                });
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
            
            // Update current position info.
            updateMarkerPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
            geocodePosition(results[0].geometry.location);

            // Add dragging event listeners.
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function () {
                updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function () {
                updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
                updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
                updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
                geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
            });

        });
        
    }

    // Onload handler to fire off the app.
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
  #mapCanvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
  }

  </style>
```

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upViewGoogleMap" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                                <tr class="clsTBRow" style="vertical-align: top">
                                                    <td style="width: 500px;">
                                                        <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                                        <div id="infoPanel">
                                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnDomainName" runat="server"/>
                                                            Location : <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" value="Rawang, Selangor" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
                                                            
                                                            <asp:Button ID="cmdGeocode" runat="server" Text="Geocode" CausesValidation="false" /><br/><br/>
                                                            <b>Marker status:</b>
                                                            <div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
                                                            <b>Current position:</b>
                                                            <div id="info"></div>
                                                            <b>Closest matching address:</b>
                                                            <div id="address"></div>
                                                            <br/>
                                                            <asp:Button ID="cmdAddPosition" runat="server" Text="Add Position" CausesValidation="false" />  
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
          </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**ISSUE 2**
domainName = 'http://localhost:10101/project/' <--- LOAD RECORD IN THE CODE BEHIND to get the current domain name

For the google map marker, I uses domainName + 'Images/maker.png' and the marker won't shows up. When I uses 'http://localhost:10101/project/Images/maker.png' and the marker shows up.

When i debug, i check both having the same results which is 'http://localhost:10101/project/Images/maker.png'

**ISSUE 3**

**ucGoogleMap.ascx Code Behind**

Currently using

```
cmdGeocode.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return codeAddress();")
```

i wan to use below code to call the javascript, but it doesn't seem like its functioning.

```
 Protected Sub cmdGeocode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGeocode.Click
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType, "codeAddress", "codeAddress();", True)
        upViewGoogleMap.Update()
    End Sub
```

Comment: I've solved the unspecified errors by adding this code in the javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved ISSUE 1 unspecified errors by adding this code in the javascript.

```
 HTMLElement.prototype.getBoundingClientRect = (function () {
    var oldGetBoundingClientRect = HTMLElement.prototype.getBoundingClientRect;
    return function () {
        try {
            return oldGetBoundingClientRect.apply(this, arguments);
        } catch (e) {
            return {
                left: '',
                right: '',
                top: '',
                bottom: ''
            };
        }
    };
})();
```

For the issues 3, I've changed the code using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript instead of ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock